# Angular.js: Why does mutating $scope with a simple helper function result in uninterpolated {{...}} expressions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Alright, here's a git diff:

```
...
function makeSomeCtrl() {
+    var identity = function (x) {return x;};
+    $scope = identity($scope)
return function($scope) {
...
```

And all of sudden, all the angular in the page "{{page.hello}}" instead of "Hello, World"

Why on Earth...?

**Edit:** Here's a Plunker demonstrating this behavior: http://plnkr.co/edit/lztwTNdAN4baVDtFLCX4?p=preview

**Resolution**
So, `$scope` wasn't in scope. D'oh! That is both meta and embarassing.

#### **Edit again: Not resolved**

The code in the Plunker, does **not** reflect the original code I was trying to debug. ie, the problem with the original code wasn't a scope error. That was an error I made while drafting the Plunker. Here's an updated Plunker that more accurately reflects the code I'm dealing with: http://plnkr.co/edit/iswQq2qqRyQjsPA4Bkk6?p=preview

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function addSomeValue(obj, x) {
      obj.value = x;
  }

  function makeCtrl(x) {
    function Ctrl($scope){
      addSomeValue($scope, x)
    }
  return Ctrl;
  }

  angular.module('modal-example', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', makeCtrl("Hello!")]);

}());
```

Results in a nice fat "{{value}}" in the rendered page.

Comment: Really need a little more context, because this is working just fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/T6zuXNFGbnkZbXSAnu97?p=preview

Comment: That's both comforting and distressing. I'll get you more contexct.

Comment: When you see uninterpolated Angular expressions `{{..}}` it typically means that there is an exception or that Angular is not running (which doesn't seem to be the case here). Check your console for errors

Comment: @Josh I forked your Plunker to make it more similar to my actual code.

Comment: When I run your plunker, I get the exception: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'RandomIdentityCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: @NewDev I don't see any errors in the Plunker console. How do I proceed?

Comment: @stewSquared Any exceptions thrown in Plunker will show up in your browser's usual console.

Comment: @ChrisBouchard Not for this one, unfortunately. This wasn't a javascript exception, but incorrect html. The value of the ng-controller attribute was incorrect. Yay for type-less html templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an easy one, `$scope` is not defined before you try to call it.

```
  function makeCtrl(someVar) {
    function identity(o){return o;}

    //Where did I come from?
    $scope = identity($scope)

    function RandomIdentityCtrl($scope){
      $scope.beforeIdentity = "Before Identity";
      $scope.afterIdentity = "After Identity";
    }
  return RandomIdentityCtrl;
  }
```

If you simply move it down into the constructor function, you will see it works just fine:

```
  function makeCtrl(someVar) {
    function identity(o){return o;}


    function RandomIdentityCtrl($scope){
      $scope.beforeIdentity = "Before Identity";

      //Now I work! Yay!
      $scope = identity($scope)

      $scope.afterIdentity = "After Identity";
    }
  return RandomIdentityCtrl;
  }
```

### Update

After reviewing the updates here: http://plnkr.co/edit/iswQq2qqRyQjsPA4Bkk6?p=preview

It would appear you just made a couple of typos.

One in your function:

```
  function makeCtrl(x) {
    function Ctrl($scope){
      addSomeValue($scope, x)
    }

  //Should be 'Ctrl'
  return RandomIdentityCtrl;
  }
```

And one in your HTML template:

```
<!-- Should be "Ctrl" -->
<div class="container" ng-controller="RandomIdentityCtrl">
```

Fixing these again results in desired behavior: http://plnkr.co/edit/eKdDPYylTCS1czwKKWew?p=preview

Comment: Injecting $scope instead of using someVar as a parameter also fixes it.

Comment: @JamesWaddington - Except that `$scope` is not available in that context since it evaluates before Angular gets ahold of it. The result is a constructor function that Angular will then use to inject into, but not the way it is being used in the example plunker.

Comment: Thanks. I need to go get some sleep :P

Comment: @Josh, the scope error you correctly identified was an error I made while editing your plunker. The original code doesn't have that error. I've updated my question appropriately. Mind taking another look?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `$scope` in `makeCtrl` because Angular won't inject it into your function. If you move the line `$scope = identity($scope)` into `RandomIdentityCtrl`, your code works fine.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error in my plunker code. Unfortunately, that doesn't actually reflect my original code. I've updated my question appropriately and included another plunker link for you to look at. Mind taking a look?

Comment: @stewSquared You changed the name of the `RandomIdentityCtrl` function, but not in any of the places it's referenced.

Comment: Thanks. It's probably something similar in the actual codebase. I hate un-typed templates